# Join 2 columns in one table based on equal values in a third column

Tags: join

I am trying to separate data within one column based on identical values in a second column. Our goal I to find out how many times each MD used a facility. Unfortunately, the table has separate entries for location and MD but identifies each with a common Document ID

```
Description      Text      Document_ID
MDname           Smith      13467
Facility         Providence 13467
MDname           Jones      14657
Facilty          Charity    14657
MDname           Smith      19834
Facility         Providence  19834
MDName           SMith      18777
Facility         Charity 18777
```

Convert to

```
Smith            Providence
Jones            Charity
Smith            Providence
Smith            Charity
```

Convert to

```
Smith            Providence    2
Smith            Charity       1
Jones            Charity       1
```

Is there a join that will join 2 columns within 1 table , using a common value of a third column ??

Comment: Are there always exactly 2 rows with same `Document_ID` and one of these rows has `'MDname'` while the other `'Facility'?`

Comment: Also, what DBMS do you use? SQL-Server, Postgres, MySQL, DB2, SQLite...?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume SQL Server here, but you can use some variation on this technique with most RDBMS I think.

You need to build a table expression representing the data you want in columns, in this example with a CTE:

```
;WITH MDs as 
(
   SELECT
       MDName = MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'MDname' THEN Text END)
      ,Facility = MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'Facility' THEN Text END)
   FROM
      MyTable
   GROUP BY
      Document_ID
)
SELECT
  MDName, Facility, COUNT(*)
FROM
  MDs
GROUP BY
  MDName, Facility
```

Comment: Your query would work in all DBMS (except MySQL, for which they would just need to convert the CTE to a derived table.)

Comment: and `Text` might be reserved in some DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for the same problem:

```
SELECT 
    a.Text   AS Name,
    b.Text   AS Facility,
    COUNT(*) AS Occurences
FROM 
    data AS a  
  JOIN  
    data AS b
      ON  a.Document_ID = b.Document_ID
WHERE 
    a.Description = 'MDname'
  AND 
    b.Description = 'Facility'
GROUP BY 
      a.Text, 
      b.Text ;
```

While for the provided data, both @JNK's and this query would provide the same (wanted) results, if your actual data are not similar, this query is more restrictive than JNK's (so take your pick, according to your needs).

If for example, for some `DocumentID` there are not exactly one row with `Text = 'MDname'` and another with `Text = 'Facility'`, these `DocumentID` will not be counted. In JNK's, they will appear with `NULL` in the respective columns.